# How do I iterate over all controls in a View

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a static table view controller. Within some of the cells, I have text boxes. I would like to enable or disable all the text boxes in one go. I know I could do something like

```
self.nameTextField.Enabled = NO; 
self.ageTextField.Enabled = NO;  
self.hairColorTextField.Enabled = NO;
```

But there has to be something more elegant. Something like

```
for (UIControl* control in self.allChildControls) { // <-- I totally just made that up.
    if ([control isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        control.Enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

I don't think I am asking the right question...

Comment: Soo... What's your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subviews` property od UIView. It contains all child UI elements.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
```

[UIView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    //check by class or tag
}
```

Comment: This needs to be done recursively if you need to dig down into the whole view structure.

Comment: So, let me see if I've got this right... when I did self.view.subviews from my TVC I got 2 UIImageView subviews. That isn't what I expected at all. I will try recursing into their subviews and see what I get. Thanks.

Comment: @SigmundFloyd I do not know what is the structure of your VC, but you should iterate on the subviews of the direct parent of your `UITextFields` or you can do it recursively as stated above. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `static` tableviewController, I am assuming you aren't allowing the user to add/delete cells. If this is the case, your question is simple. You just need to add an `outlet` to each of the `UITextField` objects and toggle it's `userInteractionEnabled` property to no.

```
self.myTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.mySecondTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you but, that is the exact pattern I am trying to avoid. I aim to make the code once, and forget about having to modify it as I add more elements to the Table.